# Why is my output predicting the same label using pretrained Alexnet in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm attempting to use a pretrained alexnet model for CIFAR10 dataset however it always predicts everything as the same class. I use the exact same code except using alexnet untrained and it works as intended. Why is it doing this?

Here is my code:

```
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
net = models.alexnet(pretrained=True).to(device)

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
     transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2, )

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.005, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(3):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels = data
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device),labels.to(device)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 2000:.3f}')
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

After the code I print the accuracy of each class. And it predicts every image as a plane.

Comment: Where is your testing code? Have you trained it with sufficient number of epochs?

Comment: I couldn't add all my code, but I assumed the problem was being caused by somewhere in the section I Included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytorch AlexNet was trained on ImageNet so the classifier is with 1000 classes.

CIFAR10 is a 10 classes dataset.

You should create a new classifier before training with CIFAR10.

I found this [post](https://analyticsindiamag.com/implementing-alexnet-using-pytorch-as-a-transfer-learning-model-in-multi-class-classification/) By Dr. Vaibhav Kumar that should explain how to do so.